# How do I capture keystrokes on the web?

Tags: php, javascript, function, input, keystroke

Using PHP, JS, or HTML (or something similar) how would I capture keystokes? Such as if the user presses ctrl+f or maybe even just f, a certain function will happen.

++++++++++++++++++++++++EDIT+++++++++++++++++++
Ok, so is this correct, because I can't get it to work. And I apologize for my n00bness  is this is an easy question, new to jQuery and still learning more and more about JS.

```
<script>    
var element = document.getElementById('capture');
    element.onkeypress = function(e) { 
       var ev = e || event;
       if(ev.keyCode == 70) {
          alert("hello");
       }
    }
</script>
<div id="capture">
Hello, Testing 123
</div>
```

++++++++++++++++EDIT++++++++++++++++++

Here is everything, but I can't get it to work:

```
<link rel="icon" href="favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon">
<style>
* {
margin: 0px
}  

div {
    height: 250px;
    width: 630px;
    overflow: hidden;
    vertical-align: top;
    position: relative;
    background-color: #999;
}
  iframe {
    position: absolute;
    left: -50px;
    top: -130px;
  }
</style>
<script>
document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].onkeyup = function(e) { 
   var ev = e || event;
   if(ev.keyCode == 70 && ev.ctrlKey) { //control+f
      alert("hello");
   }
}
</script>
<div id="capture">
Hello, Testing 123<!--<iframe src="http://www.pandora.com/" scrolling="no" width="1000" height="515"frameborder="0"></iframe>-->
</div>
```

+++EDIT+++

Thanks to Jacob, I had thought that I had it fixed, but when I tried it in FF and IE (currently using chrome, which did work) it did not work. This script is just going to be for a personal page that only I will see, so it is not the biggest deal, but for future reference, I would just like to know why this is not working in either IE or FF.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Sure, the only way to do this would be through JavaScript, and you'd do so like this:

```
window.onload = function() {
   document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].onkeyup = function(e) { 
      var ev = e || event;
      if(ev.keyCode == 70) {//&& ev.ctrlKey) {
         //do something...
      }
   }
};
```

To find out the specific key code you want, see this article: http://www.webonweboff.com/tips/js/event_key_codes.aspx

[**jsFiddle example**](http://jsfiddle.net/UexnS/1/)

Comment: Are you able to test it on JS Fiddle? It opens browser search option when I press Ctr+F in your provided link.

Comment: Just tried that replacing "do_something();" with "alert('hello')" and nothing happens when I press ctrl+f. I tried erasing the && ev.ctrlKey, and pressed just the f with still no luck.

Comment: @NAVEED You need to focus in on the `<iframe>` in the bottom right corner.

Comment: @Sean What browser are you using?

Comment: By the way, I think I'd rather have it be just f, because at the time, I wasnt thinking about it, but yes, ctrl+f opens search.

Comment: @Sean It works in the jsFiddle example for me, on Firefox, IE and Chrome.

Comment: @Sean In your example above, you're not wrapping the code in the `onload` handler. Copy-paste my updated code and try it.

Comment: @Jacob Relkin: I focused **Result** section jsFiddle but no alert.  I am using Google Chrome. Which browser you are using ?

Comment: @Sean in some (older) browsers, they fail to pass in the event object to the handler, so that line basically sets `ev` to be equal to the passed-in object if it exists, otherwise it falls back to the global `event` object.

Answer (score 2):

You're looking for the javascript events associated with key presses.  There are some annoying browser incompatibilities here, so you'll be best off using a JS library like jQuery, where you can use the jQuery keypress() method, but you can get the data you want from the javascript onkeypress event.

Comment: Ahh... ok, as I said, I am doing this for soemthing personal, not public, so browser compatibility doesnt really matter.

Answer (score 1):

You are better off capturing all keys on the window rather than capturing key strokes on a specific element like other answers referred to.

so using native javascript:

```
window.onload = function (){
 eventHandler = function (e){
    if (e.keyCode == 70 && e.ctrlKey)
    {
      //do stuff
      //console.log(e);
    }
  }

  window.addEventListener('keydown', eventHandler, false);
}
```

using JQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(window).keydown(function (e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 70 && e.ctrlKey)
    {
        //do stuff
    }

  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

**Using jQuery:**

You can do it using [`jQuery Keydown`](http://api.jquery.com/keydown/)

**Nice article on capturing different key events:**

[Working with Events in jQuery](http://www.peachpit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=1371947&seqNum=7)

**EDIT:**

**JavaScript**

Here are nice articles to do this in javascript with nice DEMO:

- [Handling Keyboard Shortcuts in JavaScript](http://www.openjs.com/scripts/events/keyboard_shortcuts/)
- [Detecting keystrokes](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/keys.html)

Comment: @NAVEEED The OP is not using jQuery.

Comment: @Jacob Relkin: Hmmmm. Ok but I think OP does not know about jQuery. So it will be a suggestion to use jQuery to do this easily.

Comment: jQuery is unnecessary in this situation. The DOM handles keyboard events quite well, and modern browser support is good. In fact, most things don't need jQuery at all.

Comment: I completely agree with @Delan