# How to enable keystrokes as commands in a web application?

Tags: html, forms, keyboard

I'm looking for a solution to a web-form issue I'm facing at the moment. I'd like to be able to use the keyboard to save web-forms - essentially a button press - but I want to keep the desktop convention of `Control+S` to save the form.

How can I handle a button press that won't cause the browser to try to save the web-page locally?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I capture keystrokes on the web?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4532773/how-do-i-capture-keystrokes-on-the-web)

Answer (score 1):

with jQuery you basically can suppress the default action of an event by firing an

```
event.preventDefault();
```

http://api.jquery.com/event.preventdefault/

But the main problem here is that browsers act different. The task has been discussed in another thread already:

[Best cross-browser method to capture CTRL+S with JQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/93695/best-cross-browser-method-to-capture-ctrls-with-jquery)