# Reading keystrokes in PHP or AJAX

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, keystrokes

I would like to get my page to read keystrokes wherever the person is focused on the website.

So like if they had the web page open and they pressed <kbd>1</kbd> then it did something and if they pressed <kbd>2</kbd> it did something else and so on. I don't mean to do this in an input tag.

How would I go about doing this? Can PHP just catch the keystroke and do something or does it have to respond back with AJAX? If so, how?

Comment: PHP is `ServerSide`! You have no access on `ClientSide` Keystrokes. Else, try to use JQuery for this: http://api.jquery.com/event.which/

If you wanna execute PHP Functions on Keystrokes, catch the KEYCODE (like "2", or sth. else and send an `AJAX Request` to the PHP Function with the keycode)

Comment: See
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4532773/how-do-i-capture-keystrokes-on-the-web

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to listen to a [keyboard event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent) with JavaScript.

PHP is a server side language and cannot help you for this.

Simple demo over here: http://jsbin.com/lamow/1/edit

```
document.addEventListener('keypress', function(event) {
  console.log(arguments);
});
```